# NMAVoiceCatalog voicePackages returns just 1 package

Tags: ios, swift, here-api

I'm using HERE iOS Premium SDK.

I need the voice navigation to use the miles/feets, not just meters and kilometers. eg. "for 2 miles continues straight".

I'm supposing that solution is in language packages if I download and install and use correct language package it will use US metrics.

So I followed the documentation and did following:

```
func checkLanguage() {
    self.voiceCatalog = NMAVoiceCatalog.sharedInstance()
    self.voiceCatalog?.delegate = self
    self.voiceCatalog?.update()
}

func voiceCatalog(_ voiceCatalog: NMAVoiceCatalog, didUpdate error: Error?) {
    for package in voiceCatalog.voicePackages {
        print("didUpdate marc \(package.marcCode) language code \(package.languageCode) name \(package.name)")
    }
}
```

I properly used NMAVoiceCatalogDelegate, didUpdate is properly called, but the problem is that in voicePackages array, there is always just one language package (en-US).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing a call to [update](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/interfacenmavoicecatalog.html#topic-apiref__updatevoicecatalog) voice catalog

And then download a voice using the [download](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/interfacenmavoicecatalog.html#topic-apiref__installvoicepackage-colon) api.
This will fetch the catalog from the server, then you can download another skin. Right now, you only have the default skin packaged in the SDK.

Comment: I'm doing update voice catalog. Right here: self.voiceCatalog?.update() or am I missing something?

Comment: You still need to download the skin after updating it. Getting the catalog just updates what is available. Make sure the voice is downloaded, then it can be used.

Comment: I know that. The problem is when I update the catalog there is only 1 element inside voiceCatalog.voicePackages array. So I don't IDs of other language packages.

Comment: That means the voice catalog update failed. Is your application registered? AFAIK your appid / token needs to be registered in order to get the full set of skins.

Comment: It's funny because error is nil :) and lastUpdate is nil. But everything else is working great, maps, navigation, and everything. But still only 1 element inside voicePackages array.